# why do we use fit() before predict() in LinearRegression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, linearmodels

Why do we use fit before giving a LinearRegression model a predict method Imean in this book I didn't even give it a proper training dataset

I mean when we give fit doesn't it just fits the data why do we need to predict something which is already known
this is just confusing
for reference if you know what this means kindly teach me too

[image: here is the Reference . i just need to know why do we use fit() and then predict(). like arent we giving housing labels the supposed outputs to the model already why are we predicting it afterwards]

I just need to know why we use fit() and then predict(). like aren't we giving housing labels -the supposed- outputs to the model already why are we predicting it afterward?

Is it for the sole purpose of only checking if our LinearRegression model is doing good or not because we are giving it the output which is housing_labels and then we predict it and then compare the two. Why? why don't we `predict()` on  test set directly?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `fit` method, you will try to achieve the least possible amount of error on your data training set by making the model learn. But you won't always (and in fact, rarely) be able to have 0 errors.

Thus you can try to use the predict `method` it on the training data, in order to obtain the training error. If the training/test/validation sets are well made, this can give you a feel about under-fitting (if the training error is too big, your model might not be adapted to the problem, or you might not have enough training data) or over-fitting (if the training error is null, you might pick on the noise present in the training data for example). Using `predict` on data from the training set has no effect on the training of the model though.

To really check if the model has trained well, you should `predict` on a test set (and maybe a validation set too if need be).

**Again `fit` makes your model learn, while `predict` only applies what the model has learned. Thus it makes little sense to use `predict` before `fit`.**

When talking about a `LinearRegressor`, the `fit` method is the one who will determine the values of the coefficients `a` and `b` in the equation `y = ax + b` of the regressor, according to the training data. Once you have these coefficients, you can use the equation to `predict` the `y` value for any `x`. And if you want to have an idea on it's performance, you'll try `x` values for which you know the `y` values (i.e. data in the training set).

Comment: Thanks so much brother, yes it does overfit on the DecisionTreeModel ...
don't wanna take your too much of time..
but can you explain what could be the reason for that??? please

Comment: To be fair, a loss equal to 0 doesn't equate to overfitting. It may also be caused by a clear separation in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Before making a prediction with your linear model you must `fit` it to the training data you have.

It makes no sense to `predict` without seeing any training samples before.

Comment: I know i don't make sense but nothing is making sense, look why do we use same data for ..
wait I think I have a wrong idea of fit() isn't it this:Any object that can estimate some parameters based on a dataset
is called an estimator (e.g., an imputer is an estimator). The estimation itself is
performed by the fit() method, and it takes only a dataset as a parameter

 doesn't it mean . fit is used to estimate nan values and stuff like that

Comment: Yes, reusing the same training samples in ``predict`` is used to compute the so called training-error, which is the difference between the true output and the predicted output. All these outputs are from the training dataset.